# Use of “in condition in which ”

Tags: synonyms

Is the use of “in a condition in which “ instead of “with” in first sentence below correct ?

> The dog was found with leg broken.

Can i say ;

> The dog was found in a condition in which its leg was broken

Comment: in a manner is an adverb. He did it in a polite manner.

Answer (score 4):

> The dog was found in a manner that its leg was broken

I'm not sure what you want this to mean. It is a strange sentence.

As given, it means that the dog's leg was broken because of the way the search for it was conducted.

The searchers were either very careless or the dog was trapped in an inaccessible place and the only way they could free it was to break its leg..

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to replace "in which" with "where". "The dog was found in a condition where it's leg was broken." flows much more naturally than, "The dog was found in a condition in which it's leg was broken."

I would say the correct way to say it would be to stick with "The dog was found with a broken leg", or, "The dog was found in a condition where it's leg was broken." based on the formats you gave.